# Breaking out of nested loop in python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops, break, turtle-graphics

i want two 'items' to move at once using this loop:

```
import turtle as t
from turtle import *
import random as r
t1=Turtle()
t2=Turtle()
turtles=[t1,t2]
for item in turtles:
  item.right(r.randint(5,500))
c=0
for i in range(500):
    for item in turtles:
       item.forward(2)
       c=c+1
       if c==1:
         yc=item.ycor()
         xc=item.xcor()
       if c==2:
         c=0
         yc2=item.ycor()
         xc2=item.xcor()
       if yc-yc2<5 or xc-xc2<5:
         break  #here is my problem
#rest of code
```

I want to exit my program using the `break` line if the object are on the same `x` or `y` line up to the nearest 5, but instead one of the objects freeze and the other one keeps going until the loop is over. How can i make my program exit that loop instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `break` statement does not work the way you want because it's a nested loop.

You should use exceptions:

```
try:
    for i in range(500):
        for item in turtles:
            ...
            if yc - yc2 < 5 or xc - xc2 < 5:
                raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    pass
```

**However, you must take care not to pass through any unanticipated errors that you should actually catch!**

Consider putting your code into a function to avoid all this hassle:

```
def move_turtles(turtles):
    for i in range(500):
        for item in turtles:
            ...
            if yc - yc2 < 5 or xc - xc2 < 5:
                return

move_turtles(turtles)
# rest of code
```

Comment: Don't bother making your own Exception class, there's just no need and it obfuscates your code

Comment: @KindStranger Duly noted. Updated the answer as well.

Comment: Doesn't this drag us into the issue [exceptions as control flow considered a serious antipattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189225) since exceptions are being used for things that aren't really exceptional?  And if this really is an exceptional case, then reusing a non-applicable existing exception to save effort seems the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @cdlane [Python endorses EAFP style of coding](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/06/29/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/), and thus exceptions are pretty cheap compared to other languages. However, you can hear [arguments from both sides](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351110/are-exceptions-for-flow-control-best-practice-in-python) regarding this issue.

Comment: @cdlane Please check my updated answer. You might be more comfortable with that. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is known as **breaking out of a nested loop.**
Here is one solution, among many.

```
stop = False

for j in i:
    if stop:
        break
    #Do stuff
    for k in j:
        #Do more stuff
        if (condition):
            stop = True
            break #breaks (for k in j) loop
```